# Best test for transitivity using Haskell's Quickcheck

Tags: haskell, testing

Of the three tests below which is the best test for transitivity. This follows from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896137/using-haskells-quickcheck-to-check-transitivity). The usual logical rule of transitivity (R(a,b) and R(b,c)) => R(a,c) does not seem  apply in this case.Hence, I think that `prop_trans3`  would be not be a good test,  because each of the three terms represents a different stack.
But  which of `prop_trans1` and `prop_trans2` are best suited to testing transitivity?

```
import Test.QuickCheck
data Block = Block Int deriving (Show,Eq)
-- MoveOnto(bl,b2,s) is read as b2 is moved into and onto bl on stack or table.
data Stack = EmptyTable  |  MoveOnto Block Block Stack deriving  (Show,Eq) 
isOn :: Block -> Block -> Stack -> Bool
isOn b1 b2 (MoveOnto b3 b4 s) |  ((b1 == b3) && (b4 == b2)) || (isOn b4 b2 s)   =  True
isOn _ _ _  = False

instance Arbitrary (Block) where
  arbitrary = fmap Block arbitrary

instance Arbitrary (Stack) where
  arbitrary = oneof [return EmptyTable, MoveOnto <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary <*> arbitrary]

prop_trans1 b1 b2 s      =  isOn b1 b2 (MoveOnto b1 b2 s)
prop_trans2 b1 b2 b3 s   =  isOn b3 b1 (MoveOnto b3 b2 (MoveOnto b2 b1 s))
prop_trans3 b1 b2 b3 s   =  ((isOn b2 b1 (MoveOnto b2 b1 s)) && (isOn b3 b2 (MoveOnto b3 b2 s))) <=  (isOn b3 b1 (MoveOnto b3 b1 s))
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `MoveOnto (Block 1) (Block 0) (MoveOnto (Block 2) (Block 1) EmptyTable)`? What is the full relation of which blocks are on which other blocks for this `Stack`?

Comment: @Daniel The term 'MoveOnto (Block 1) (Block 0) (MoveOnto (Block 2) (Block 1) EmptyTable)' constructs a 'Stack' where transitivity does not hold.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Are you asking us to read your mind and figure out what properties you are expecting to hold?

Comment: I am only concerned with stacks that are constructed in the context of isOn. It is the in this context I wish to test transitivity.

Comment: I don't understand what "constructed in the context of `isOn`" means. In your code, `isOn` does not construct a stack (though it does consume one).

Comment: You are of course correct! But I hope that `IsOn` at least offers a decision procedure for transitivity.

Comment: What is the relation whose transitivity you believe is being checked by `isOn`?

Comment: I believe that `on` is the relation based on  [paper](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~andrea/papers/Cosit97.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual definition of transitivity *does* apply, even in this case.

```
prop_trans a b c s = (r a b && r b c) ==> r a c
    where r x y = isOn x y s
```

Unfortunately checking this property will lead to *a lot* of discards. You can do a lot better just by drawing `a`, `b`, and `c` from blocks that appear in `s`:

```
listBlocks (MoveOnto b1 b2 s) = b1:b2:listBlocks s
listBlocks EmptyTable = []

prop_trans2 s = do
    [a,b,c] <- replicateM 3 . elements . listBlocks $ s
    return (prop_trans a b c s)
```

It's possible to do better still, but seems not to be necessary, as this gets me a counterexample pretty quickly:

```
> quickCheckWith stdArgs { maxDiscardRatio = 1000 } prop_trans2
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 6 tests):  
MoveOnto (Block 4) (Block (-2)) (MoveOnto (Block (-2)) (Block 4) (MoveOnto (Block 2) (Block 5) EmptyTable))
```